# Get parent element id while parsing json data with jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to print ID of parent element when child element value is `client_release` from JSON data.

if
    data.properties.value== "client_release"

then output should be

```
abcd1g2f,hirk5d7b3l
```

I tried below, but no luck

```
jq '.data[].properties[]|select(.value=="client_release")|.id'
```

JSON data is below:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"abcd1g2f",
         "resourceURI":"https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/abcd1g2f",
         "name":"release1",
         "description":"release1",
         "type":"target",
         "userManaged":true,
         "properties":[  
            {  
               "key":"repositoryGroupId",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "key":"method",
               "value":"create,read"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryId",
               "value":"client_release"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryTargetId",
               "value":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"asdf1k4g",
         "resourceURI":"https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/asdf1k4g",
         "name":"release2",
         "description":"release2",
         "type":"target",
         "userManaged":true,
         "properties":[  
            {  
               "key":"repositoryGroupId",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "key":"method",
               "value":"read"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryId",
               "value":"formal_release"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryTargetId",
               "value":"1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"hirk5d7b3l",
         "resourceURI":"https://somerepo.com/service/local/privileges/hirk5d7b3l",
         "name":"release3",
         "description":"release3",
         "type":"target",
         "userManaged":true,
         "properties":[  
            {  
               "key":"repositoryGroupId",
               "value":""
            },
            {  
               "key":"method",
               "value":"create,read"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryId",
               "value":"client_release"
            },
            {  
               "key":"repositoryTargetId",
               "value":"1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is right, but the `data[]` array should be outside the `select` statement,

```
jq '.data[] | select(.properties[].value == "client_release") | .id'
```

To put it in the CSV format as indicated in the question, put the result into an array and use the `@csv` construct

```
jq --raw-output '[.data[] | select(.properties[].value == "client_release") | .id] | @csv'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following filter avoids duplications and might be more efficient than using select(.properties[].value ...):

```
.data
| map(select(.properties | any(.[]; .value == "client_release")) | .id)
| join(",")
```

(You could alternatively use `@csv` at the end if you want the values of .id as JSON strings.)

### "repositoryId"

If attention should only be paid to the value corresponding to "repositoryId", then you could
use `from_entries`, e.g.:

```
.data
| map(select(.properties | from_entries.repositoryId == "client_release") | .id)
| join(",")
```